# Call a TSQL PROC for processing records instead of Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Pardon me for a silly question if it may sound like as I am a SharePoint novice right now.

I have a SP form that various users will use to add some assessment values. The form looks something like below

[image]

I have blacked out sensitive info.

What I wish to do is call a TSQL stored proc to commit data entered in every row. The reasoning to do is that there are multiple business level logic to be processed before a commit can be done. This has to be done when the Save button is hit.

The data in this form grid is loaded from a TSQL view. The editable fields are "Adherence", "Comment", "Exemption Time Period".

Is their any OOB feature to do this or we need to write JavaScript, C# classes in the form?